# How to set global variable in different file

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global Variable from a different file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400525/global-variable-from-a-different-file-python)

is that possible to set variable in different file ?

So I have two different files somewhat like this..

### tes1.py

```
import test2
st = 'a'
def main():
  mis = input('puts: ')
  print tes2.set(mis)
main()
```

### tes2.py

```
def set(object):
  pics = ['''
  %s
  1st
  '''%st,
  '''
  %s
  2nd
  ''']
  return pics[object]
```

and i execute tes1.py and issued an error:

```
NameError: global name 'st' is not defined
```

thanks for the respond

Comment: Why aren't you passing that as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips:

- Wrap your `main()` function in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. It prevents imported modules from executing code that should not be run when being imported. I usually do away with `main()` completely and just write all my main code in the `if` block.
- `object` is a built-in type. Don't name things `object`. Also `set`, as that is a type as well.
- Global variables are discouraged, as there is *always* a way to make global variables into parameters (unless your global variables are constants, which is fine).

Here's how I would do it:

**test1.py**:

```
import test2

if __name__ == '__main__':
  st = 'a'
  mis = input('puts: ')

  print tes2.rename_me_set(st, mis)
```

**test2.py**:

```
def rename_me_set(st, obj):
  pics = ['''
  %s
  1st
  ''' % st,
  '''
  %s
  2nd
  ''']

  return pics[obj]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you really don't want to do that. I'd pass `st` in as an argument to `set()`. However the following (bad) setup works:

### lib.py

```
var = "woo"
```

### exec.py

```
import lib
print lib.var
```

(Note that just importing `lib.py` into `exec.py` does not enable me to use variables from `exec.py` in `lib.py`, only the other way around. Think about how that applies to your situation.)