# Setting and getting variables in .Net hosted IronPython script

Tags: .net, ironpython

I'm trying to prototype a validation rules engine using IronPython hosted in a .Net console application. I've stripped the script right down to what I believe is the basics

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
engine.Execute("from System import *");
engine.Runtime.Globals.SetVariable("property_value", "TB Test");
engine.Runtime.Globals.SetVariable("result", true);

var sourceScope = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("result = property_value != None and len(property_value) >= 3");
sourceScope.Execute();

bool result = engine.Runtime.Globals.GetVariable("result");

engine.Runtime.Shutdown();
```

It can't however detect the global variables that I think I have set up. It fails when the script is executed with

```
global name 'property_value' is not defined
```

but i can check the global variables in the scope and they are there - this statement returns true when I run in in the debugger

```
sourceScope.Engine.Runtime.Globals.ContainsVariable("property_value")
```

I am a complete newbie with IronPython so apologies if this is an easy/obvious question.

The general motivation to this is creating [this kind of rules engine](http://www.codevoyeur.com/articles/5/a-simple-ironpython-business-object-validation-framework.aspx) but with a later (most recent) version of IronPython where some of the methods and signatures have changed.

Comment: Stuff you put in to the `ScriptRuntime.Globals` scope must be imported. It's not the same as declaring a global variable accessible in any scope, at least, not in IronPython.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the way I would provide script with a variable and pick the results afterwards:

```
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        scope.SetVariable("foo", 42);
        engine.Execute("print foo; bar=foo+11", scope);
        Console.WriteLine(scope.GetVariable("bar"));
```

Answer (score 3):

To add onto Pawal's answer, the variables set in this manner are not "global" and can't be accessed by imported functions.  I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874688/hosted-ironpython-import-files-which-contain-custom-functions), that this is how to make them global and accessible by all:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
engine.GetBuiltinModule().SetVariable("foo", 42);
```