# Changing dictionaries of functions - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, global-variables

So I've been creating a fairly basic rpg in my spare time, but I've reached a stumbling block. I want to make it so that only certain functions are accessible at a certain time by changing a dictionary of commands every time the player goes into/exits battle. However, the loop I set up for searching through the dictionary keys doesn't seem to work for any commands except for the ones initially written.

**Main file:**

```
    from commands import *

    Commands = {
        "travel": Player.travel,
        "explore": Player.explore,
        "help": Player.help,
        }

    p = Player()

    while (john_hero.health > 0):
        line = raw_input("=> ")
        args = line.split()
        if len(args) > 0:
            commandFound = False
            for c in Commands.keys():
                    if args[0] == c[:len(args[0])]:
                            Commands[c](p)
                            commandFound = True
                            break
            if not commandFound:
                    print "John's too simple to understand your complex command."
```

**command.py**

```
            class Player:
                def __init__(self):
                    self.state = "normal"
                    john_hero = John()
                    self.location = "Town"
                    global Commands
                    Commands = {
                            "attack": Player.attack,
                            "flee": Player.flee,
                            "help": Player.help
                            }
                def fight(self):
                    Player.state = "fight"
                    global Commands
                    enemy_a = Enemy()
                    enemy_name = enemy_a.name
                    print "You encounter %s!" % (enemy_name)
```

*Note: The loop was taken from someone else's code. I'm using it since I'm creating the game mostly for learning purposes.

Comment: where is the code that modifies `Commands` ?

Comment: @arunkumar Ah, I've just added it. In retrospect it was rather foolish of me not to include it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code in `command.py` trying to modify a global variable that is defined in `Main file`, in other words, something like this: [Global Variable from a different file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400525/global-variable-from-a-different-file-python)

This doesn't work because your code now has two `Commands` variables, one in the scope of `command.py`, one in the scope of `Main file`. Rather than trying to make two files share a global variable (which is a rather terrible idea IMO), I suggest you make `Commands` an attribute of `Player`:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.Commands = {
            "attack": Player.attack,
            "flee": Player.flee,
            "help": Player.help
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like

```
commands = {"travel":{"cmd":Player.travel, "is_available":True}}
for key in commands:
    if commands[key]["is_available"]:
        print "do stuff"
```

but as pointed out by @arunkumar it is going to be difficult to answer this question without more of the code.