# Dumping Python Variable into another file

Tags: python, file, variables, global, dump

I want to do something similar to that outlined here:

[Global Variable from a different file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400525/global-variable-from-a-different-file-python)

However I believe that I am not getting an output from the variable file.foo because foo is not explicitly defined in file.py. Foo is an array of matrices created from a readfile. file.py appends values from the readfile to foo thus file.py must run independently to define foo.

Because of this, I am wondering if there is a way to dump the definition of the python variable to some location that I can call from later. My other alternative is to dump this variable to a txt file which I really dont want to do to avoid extraneous file creation and other complications.

Edit:

This is what I have:

```
color_matrices = Full_Layout(array=org_arr, resolution=1)

def Globalize_RPF():
     global color_matrices
```

Then I am trying to call color_matrices in my current pyfile like so:

```
 from ThreeD_Core_Distribution import color_matrices
 RPF = color_matrices
 print(RPF)
```

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer but I'm not quite really sure if I understood your question. You referred to this question: [Global Variable from a different file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400525/global-variable-from-a-different-file-python)

> *However I believe that I am not getting an output from the variable `file.foo` because `foo` is not explicitly defined in `file.py`. `foo` is an array of matrices created from a readfile.*

You referred to `file.foo` as not explicitly defined in `file`. What I understand from your statement is that, `foo` lives within another object that lives in `file` module. So in order to get `foo` you need to fetch it through that object:

```
import file 
file.object.foo
```

*or:*

```
import file *
object.foo
```

> *`file.py` appends values from the readfile to `foo` thus `file.py` must run independently to define `foo`.*

You would basically import `file` module in order to append the values from the readfile. Hence, within `file` you would open the readfile to append its values to `foo` which is basically an object of `file`: `file.foo`.

I just hope that I got your what you're asking about.

**Edit:**

Let's suppose the code you posted is in a module file called `file`:

```
color_matrices = Full_Layout(array=org_arr, resolution=1)

def Globalize_RPF():
    global color_matrices
```

`color_matrices` is global because it's assigned at the top-level of the module. This statement `global color_matrices` inside `Globalize_RPF` function will declare that you intend to change the global variable `color_matrices`:

```
def Globalize_RPF():
    color_matrices = Full_Layout(array=org_arr, resolution=1)  # Local to function, you cannot use `file.foo` after importing `file` module
```

When assigned this way, `color_matrices` is local to the function. What does that mean? It means the variable won't be accessible outside the function. So even if you try to use  `color_matrices` after the function in `file` module, it won't work.

```
color_matrices = Full_Layout(array=org_arr, resolution=1)      # Top-level assignment, global var

def Globalize_RPF():
    # process color_matrices
```

Now `color_matrices` is a global variable, that's you can use it inside `file` module in functions, classes, in expressions and many other places, you can reference the variable anywhere in `file` because its global now. Because `color_matrices` is global now and not a local variable inside a function, we can get its value by importing `file` like the following:

```
 from file import color_matrices
 RPF = color_matrices
 print(RPF)
```

If you need to re-assign `color_matrices` to new results inside the function, use `global` keyword:

```
def Globalize_RPF():
    global color_matrices
    color_matrices = ...          # Changes global color_matrices
```

If you use only `color_matrices = ...` inside the function body  you'll simply create `color_matrices` that's local to the function and you'll shadow/override `color_matrices` of the global scope, the one that's assigned at the top of the module.

Comment: So maybe thats the problem: foo does not live within an object in the file module. Rather it is simply a variable defined by a custom function that parses the readfile. So when I attempt to print(file.foo) in my current pyfile, nothing is returned. Maybe having foo live in an object is the solution? I am not an expert in python so Im not sure I would know how to do this.

Comment: Ok, since `foo` is a local variable in a function, it's accessible by that function and any enclosing functions if there's any. In order to make `foo` accessible when you qualify its name through the module name: `file.foo`, you need to move the assignment to the global scope. That's, either you declare `foo` global within the function like: `global foo` and then you assign whatever values to `foo`: `foo = ...` within the function or you move the assignment of `foo` outside the function, at the top-level of the module.

Comment: please see edit, I clearly dont know what i am doing

Comment: I dont get any errors in what I am doing but it may also be worth noting that when I add " from ThreeD_Core_Distribution import color_matrices" to my current pyfile, nothing is printable. Why is this?

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand better now. I originally had the top level assignment in your third code block and I do not intend to change color_matrices in the current pyfile so I guess I do not need the function in your first code block. The problem now is, I am doing exactly what your 3rd and 4th code blocks say (without the function in 3rd) and I cannot get an output for RPF. In fact, nothing will print as long as "from file import color_matrices" is in my code

Comment: @SterlingButters Have you tried to print `color_matrices` directly: `print(name_matrices)?` And make sure you initialized `Full_Layout` object correctly. If nothing prints and no exception was raised, I believe you're having a problem with your object or perhaps another name rebinding somewhere in your file to a same-named variable.