# python: Print variable name of args received from another file

Tags: python, string, variables, global-variables

I need to print variable names, so I did:

```
def get_variable_name(x):
    local_matches = [k for k, v in locals().items() if v is x]
    global_matches = [k for k, v in globals().items() if v is x]

    print(local_matches, global_matches)
    return global_matches[0]

a = 5
print(get_variable_name(a))

# output
# (['x'], ['a'])
# a
```

That's now perfect, but now I need to use this `get_variable_name` function in many places in my project. So I moved this function to `utils.py`, and we can now import it and use it like:

```
from scripts.utils import get_variable_name
a = 5
print(get_variable_name(a))

# output
# (['x'],[])
# ! can't access index 0 exception
# ! since the list is empty
```

Clearly, in the former, a is found in the global var stack and in the latter it's not, since when it's inside of `utils.py` executing this functions, `globals()` does not contain `a`, since it is not declared in the global scope (of the file).

So we got `locals().items()` to give local vars, and `globals().items()` for global vars, **How do I access inter-file scope variable stack?**

---

UPDATE:

In another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3400525/3125070), mentioned in the comments, they are dealing with variables defined in the global scope in `file1` and this will not be available in `file2` because, `file1` imports  only modules of `file2`.

But here, I am sending these variables to `file2`, and obviously, values of which it`file2` has access to, but how do I access the names of the arguments passed? (And I don't see a security or dependency flaw associated with this, as it already has access to the variable, I just want their names)

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6486008/3125070

Comment: I think i found a post that has answered the same question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400525/global-variable-from-a-different-file-python

Comment: It is not recommended.
Can create lots of bugs and exceptions if you do.
You should read more about cyclical dependency.

Comment: @Max updated the qustion

Comment: As you said you are sending the value of the parameter `a` to  `file2`,
Thus the value of `x` in `file2` is the same as the value of `a` in `file1`.
The function works perfectly fine, it dosent know that there is another parameter that is called a, you pass the value, and so it knows only of the existing of `x`.
You are not letting `file2` manipulate variable `a` directly, which is why it does not recognizes any additional params.

Comment: @Max Not all the args are passed by value, sometimes, internally python will take the reference of the data structure, for eg. mutation happens on the same list object. Perhaps this needs a little more digging deep?

Comment: There are mutable and immutable objects.
In short, if you pass a mutable object, you pass a reference to it.
In this case it dosent matter, the point is that you *pass* an argument to a function.
You dont create a new parameter in `file2`, you only pass a value in an already existing parameter, that why `gloabl()` wont show you two params.
As said above, if you want it to catch the params in `file1`, you have to use the import * state in `file2` which will create cyclical dependency.