# python: state of imported global variables holding a reference to lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, global, python-import

**Backstory**:
I was trying implementing one way to handle `-v` parameters to increase the verbosity of an application. To that end, I wanted to use a global variable that is pointing to an empty lambda function initially. If `-v` is given the variable is changed and gets another lambda function assigned that does print it input.

**MWE**:
I noticed that this did not work as expected when calling the lambda function from another module after importing it via `from x import *`...

mwe.py:

```
from mod import *
import mod

def f():
  vprint("test in f")

vprint("test before")
print("before: %d" % foo)
set_verbosity(1)
vprint("test after")
print("after: %d" % foo)
f()
mod.vprint("explicit: %d" % mod.foo)
modf()
```

mod.py:

```
vprint = lambda *a, **k: None
foo = 42

def set_verbosity(verbose):
  global vprint, foo
  if verbose > 0:
    vprint = lambda *args, **kwargs: print(*args, **kwargs)
    foo = 0

def modf():
  vprint("modf: %d" % foo)
```

The output is

```
before: 42
after: 42
explicit: 0
modf: 0
```

where the "explicit" and "modf" outputs are due to the `mod.vprint` and `modf` calls at the end of the mwe. All other invocations of `vprint` (that go through the imported version of `vprint`) are apparently not using the updated definition. Likewise, the value of `foo` seems to be imported only once.

**Question**:
It looks to me as if the `from x import *` type of imports copies the state of the globals of the imported module. I am not so much interested in workarounds per se but the actual reason for this behavior. Where is this defined in the documentation and what's the rationale?

**Workaround**:
As a side note, one way to implement this anyway is to wrap the global lambda variables by functions and export only them:

```
_vprint = lambda *a, **k: None

def vprint(*args, **kwargs):
  _vprint(*args, **kwargs)

def set_verbosity(verbose):
  global _vprint
  if verbose > 0:
    _vprint = lambda *args, **kwargs: print(*args, **kwargs)
```

This makes it work with the import-from way that allows the other module to simply call `vprint` instead of explicitly deferencing via the module's name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Variable from a different file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400525/global-variable-from-a-different-file-python)

Comment: No, that deals with the same issue but does not explain **why** it works like that nor where it is documented. (Neither does the often referenced FAQ entry on the topic: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules).

Comment: the python tag has a fair share of experts answering regularly, I hope someone will supply some insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random stab in the dark ahead:

[If you look at the docs for `__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__), there's the bit:

> On the other hand, the statement `from spam.ham import eggs, sausage as saus` results in
>
> ```
> _temp = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), ['eggs', 'sausage'], 0)
> eggs = _temp.eggs
> saus = _temp.sausage
> ```

I think this is the key. If we infer that `from mod import *` results in something like:

```
_temp = __import__('mod', globals(), locals(), [], 0)
printv = _temp.printv
foo = _temp.foo
```

This shows what the problem is. `printv` is a reference to the old version of `printv`; what `mod.printv` was pointing to at the time of import. Reassigning what the `printv` in `mod` is pointing to doesn't effect anything in `mwe`, because the `mwe` reference to `printv` is still looking at the previous lambda.

It's similar to how this doesn't change `b`:

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
```

`b` is still pointing to `1`, because reassigning `a` doesn't effect what `b` is looking at.

On the other hand, `mod.printv` *does* work because we are now using a direct reference to the global in `mod` instead of a reference that points to `printv` in `mod`.

---

This was a random stab because I think I know the answer based on some random reading I did awhile ago. If I'm incorrect, please let me know and I'll remove this to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks, very insightful and well referenced (pun intended). I'd still like to know why it is implemented that way (because it seems rather insane from the user's PoV and the myriad of questions on the internet on the topic proofs that all too well - maybe including the one above ;) After all, the behavior seems to be very exotic and I don't know other languages that do it that way (not even Perl is so peculiar(!)).

Comment: @stefanct I'm not sure we can answer the justification. It may be oversight on BDFL's part, or a poorly-documented-but-intentional result of how `import`s work. The idea may have been that relying on globals is bad, and relying to mutating globals across files is even worse, so it shouldn't be a problem in any good code. Idk.

Comment: Since Python has functions as first-class citizens I disagree because as shown in this very example global variables and (exported) functions **would** be interchangeable if the export/import would be implemented differently. NB: I don't modify the global variable across files but only within the module that defines it (exactly for the reasons global variables are usually deemed bad: breaking encapsulation). And that a function changes functionality because some other function within the same module/class is called before that, is perfectly normal behavior and the reason getters/setters exists

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: when you do `from module import *`, you're *copying the names and their associated references*; changing the reference associated with the original name does not change the reference associated with the copy.**

---

This deals with the underlying difference between *names* and *references*. The underlying reason for the behavior has to do with how python handles such things.

Only one thing is truly immutable in python: memory. You can't change individual bytes directly. However, almost everything in python deals with *references to* individual bytes, and you can change those references. When you do `my_list[2] = 5`, you're not changing any memory - rather, you're allocating a new block of memory to hold the value `5`, and pointing the second index of `my_list` to it. The original data that `my_list[2]` used to be pointing at is still there, but since nothing refers to it any more, the garbage collector will take care of it eventually and free the memory it was using.

The same principle goes with names. Any given namespace in python is comparable to a `dict` - each name has a corresponding reference. And this is where the problems come in.

Consider the difference between the following two statements:

```
from module import *
```

```
import module
```

In both cases, `module` is loaded into memory.

In the latter case, only one thing is added to the local namespace - the name `'module'`, which references the entire memory block containing the module that was just loaded. Or, well, it references the memory block of that module's own namespace, which itself has references to all the names in the module, and so on all the way down.

In the former case, however, every name in `module`'s namespace is copied into the local namespace. The same block of memory still exists, but instead of having *one* reference to *all* of it, you now have *many* references to *small parts* of it.

---

Now, let's say we do both of those statements in succession:

```
from module import *
import module
```

This leaves us with one name `'module'` referencing all the memory the module was loaded into, and a bunch of other names that reference individual parts of that block. We can verify that they point to the same thing:

```
print(module.func_name == func_name)
# True
```

But now, we try to assign something else to `module.attribute`:

```
module.func_name = lambda x:pass
print(module.func_name == func_name)
# False
```

It's no longer the same. Why?

Well, when we did `module.func_name = lambda x:pass`, we first allocated some memory to store `lambda x:pass`, and then we changed `module`'s `'func_name'` name to reference that memory instead of what it was referencing. Note that, like the example I gave earlier with lists, we didn't change the thing that the `module.func_name` was previously referencing - it still exists, and the local `func_name` continues to reference it.

So when you do `from module import *`, you're *copying the names and their associated references*; changing the reference associated with the original name does not change the reference associated with the copy.

---

The workaround for this is to not do `import *`. In fact, this is pretty much the ultimate reason *why* using `import *` is usually considered poor practice, save for a handful of special cases. Consider the following code:

```
# module.py
variable = "Original"
```

```
# file1.py
import module

def func1():
    module.variable = "New"
```

```
# file2.py
import module
import file1

print(module.variable)
file1.func1()
print(module.variable)
```

When you run `python file2.py`, you get the following output:

```
Original
New
```

Why? Because `file1` and `file2` both imported `module`, and in both of their namespaces `'module'` is pointing to the same block of memory. `module`'s namespace contains a name `'variable'` referencing some value. Then, the following things happen:

1. `file2` says "okay, `module`, please give me the value associated with the name `'variable'` in your namespace.
2. `file1.func1()` says "okay, `module`, the name `'variable'` in your namespace now references this other value.
3. `file2` says "okay, `module`, please give me the value associated with the name `'variable'` in your namespace.

Since `file1` and `file2` are still both talking to the same bit of memory, they stay coordinated.

Comment: Upvote for that list example! Learn something everyday, I had no idea each list cell was a separate reference.

Comment: @kabanus It's also something you can realize naturally, when you consider "How can objects of arbitrary size (like strings) be stored in array-style lists (which would be necessary for performance reasons)"? If you conceptualize it in C terms, the answer is "you'd use pointers, obviously" - like, an array of strings is actually just an array of `char*`, with each string allocated independently. But for that behavior to be consistent for *all* objects, then clearly *every* object is referred to by its reference when you put it into a list. And things follow logically from there.

Comment: That's only true if it *has* to be consistently implemented for all objects. But it does not. Perl for example does not store pointers to integers in lists.