# If there are two python files say 1.py and 2.py, will a variable declared as global in file1.py also be global in file2.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, global

suppose there is a variable "age" in 1.py and it is declared global inside 1.py. will the same variable "age" also be automatically declared as global in 2.py, and any other subsequent python files in the same directory?

Comment: Global declarations are in individual functions, not files.

Comment: But in general, nothing in one file affects any other file, unless you import one of them into the other.

Comment: A good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3400652/10498119

Comment: tysm @SubirVerma